# Calling a reference in an output variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to use an output variable to call on a database reference `[$(Reservations)]`. However, when I try this below:

```
OUTPUT '' +[$(Reservations)]+ '.dbo.Product'        
    INTO @OutputList
```

It does not give me any errors in the error list in my build, but when I try to publish this, then it states an error that Reservations is an invalid column.
How can I get this reference `+[$(Reservations)]+` included in the output variable? I need it to call this so that it doesn't matter if the name of the database is changed as we are always using this to refer to it.

Comment: What is a database reference?   A concept from another RDBMS?   `$` doesn't have any special significance in SQL Server that I'm aware of.

Comment: What do you mean by publish?  what platform are you using?  This looks like it could be shell script or javascript -- what is this?

Comment: Using visual studio where I have create stored procs. After creating the profs, right click on my solution and click on publish so it goes onto my local machine where I xan use management studio to test my procs

Comment: $ does have significance as we declared the variable as this. The variable is called $(Reservations), so no matter that if we change the database name to let's say 'Res' because we are using the variable to call the database, we don't need to change any code to match the db name

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted isn't valid TSQL as far as I'm aware.

If you've got a variable in your SQL called Reservations, the code you'd want would be

```
OUTPUT '[' + @Reservations + '].dbo.Product'        
INTO @OutputList
```

But my guess is that your code is inadvertently mixing languages and isn't actually executed itself on SQL Server but built in another language and passed to SQL Server. If we can get to the bottom of what language your [$(Reservations)] variable is defined in, we can get to the bottom of this :-)

Comment: of course, the quoted code would only output that object _name_, not contents. agreed the question is way too unclear

Comment: It's used in visual studio in the stored procedure (.sl), file, when published, it's shown as [Reservations], automatically. This does work when I just reference a table and perform this procedure, but just don't know how it should be done on an output